# Scrapy, with Python 3.4 is failing in terminal

Tags: python, scrapy

```
File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 7, in <module>
    from scrapy.cmdline import execute
ImportError: No module named scrapy.cmdline
```

I am getting this when attempting to make a new project in mac terminal.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scrapy [doesn't work on Python 3](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html#does-scrapy-work-with-python-3):

> Scrapy is supported under Python 2.7 only. Python 2.6 support was
>   dropped starting at Scrapy 0.20.